# How to access a method of an subclass object from a List

Tags: java, inheritance, subclass

I have a class `Sprites` and a class `Soldier`, `Tank` and so on. `Soldier` and `Tank` extends `Sprites`. Now the subclasses have a special `update()` method which is different in each class (like different movement and so on).

I have a `List<Sprites> ListUnits1Player1` where all objects of e.g. Soldiers are stored and also a `List<Sprites> ListUnits2Player1` where all objects of Tanks are stored. These lists are of the type `<Sprites>`. Now please see the follwing code:

```
        for(Iterator<Sprites> itr_unit1_player1 =     ListUnits1Player1.iterator();itr_unit1_player1.hasNext();) {
        Sprites unit1_player1 = itr_unit1_player1.next();
        unit1_player1.update();
    }
```

I get an error can't resolve method `update()`.

The debugger tells me however, that unit1_player1 is of type `Soldier`, which is correct since I stored the objects of `Soldier` in the List `ListUnits1Player1`.

But then why can't I call the method `update()` of the class Soldier?

I guess I could explicitly cast `unit1_player1` to `Soldier` with `((Soldier)unit1_player1).update();` but since it is variable which unit (Soldier, Tank,...) is stored in `ListUnits1Player1` I don't want to cast it to a certain type.

I have tried casting with:

```
unitClass = unit1_player1.getClass();
((unitClass)unit1_player1).update();
```

to always get the correct class, but this just gives me the error `Unknown class 'unitClass'`

Any suggestions?

Comment: Post the classes. I'm guessing `update()` is not `public`?

Comment: The update() method should simply be declared (possibly as an abstract method) in the class Sprite, and overridden in subclasses. To make your code readable, you should also learn to indent it properly, and to respect the Java naming conventions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can not call `unpdate` on `Sprites`, means you did not declare `update` method in the super class or declare it as private.

It's always a good habit to use `override` annotation:

```
class Sprites {
    void update() {

    }
}

class Tank extends Sprites {

    @Override
    void update() {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could move the method `update` in the parent class `Sprites` as an abstract method.

The subclasses then will have to override the method and `unit1_player1.update();` would work without any cast.

Comment: thanks for your answer. With override works. But declaring the method in superclass as abstract would mean I need to declare the entire class as abstract. I went with @Sun s answer but yours is basically the same and works (without the abstract). Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Put your `update` method as abstract in`Sprites` class.

```
//superclass
public abstract void update ();
```

Then override it in each subclass

```
//subclass
public void update (){
    //code
}
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. With override works. But declaring the method in superclass as abstract would mean I need to declare the entire class as abstract.

Comment: @Mirco oh yeah you're right.
But that doesn't matter, does it? Still works then.

Answer (score 0):

You declared an iterator over `Sprite`s, so from the compiler's point of view, you could be dealing with any subtype of that, but there's no way to know which

If you will only ever have objects in your collection that support `update`, you should declare an interface for that method, make both `Soldier` and `Tank` implement it, and then debate your collection as containing objects of that interface type.